# Commits to SQLite database lost every time program re-runs

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I have an embedded SQLite database that loses all its data every the program is run.

The insertion of data works fine for an instance of the application. I've tried querying the database after the insertion of data, and the data shows up as expected.

Querying the SQlite database after the application closes also revealed that the data is still stored in the database.

So I don't think the issue is with the connection or commit portions of the JDBC, since the Application clearly could connect and commit to the SQLite database.

However, upon relaunching the application, all the data in the SQLite database is lost. Only the data is wiped, the schema is fine.

**Update**
As Mark has pointed out, I am indeed storing my SQLite database in my resource folder. When built, the resource folder is packaged into a jar, which he suggested was the reason for my issues, since jar files are read-only. The jar that was produced when my build was compiled did run into issues, crashing whenever it was executed.

However, the embededded SQLite database that is losing data is the database that is found in my project/build/resources/main/finDB.sqlite file path. So I don't think that it is a jar issue. If it helps, I'm running the application using the 'run' task provided by the gradle application plugin. I'm not recompiling the project, but merely running and closing the compiled project. Between these cycles of run and close, my DB will then lose all the data that has been added by the instance of the project that had just run earlier.

**Code that I wrote**

This is the utility class that I use to create my connections to the SQLite database.

```java
    public class DBUtil {
        private String getFileFromResources(String fileName) {
            URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
            if (resource == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("file is not found!");
            } else {
                return resource.getFile();
            }
        }

        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            String fileName = getFileFromResources("sql/finDB.sqlite");
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlite:" + fileName;
            return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        }
    }
```

This is an example of the insertion methods I wrote to connect and commit an insertion transaction to the SQLlite database.

```java
    public static void addAccountGroup(String accountGroup) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS_GROUP (ACCOUNTS_GROUP_NAME) VALUES (?)";
            try  (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = new DBUtil().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql)) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1,accountGroup);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "embedded SQLite database", do you mean the database file is stored inside a `jar` file? If so, the behaviour is expected. Files in a jar file are effectively read-only.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for replying! The DB is indeed in my resource folder, and is indeed being built into the jar. That does explain why my executable jar closes all connection to the DB and crashes whenever I run it. However, the error I'm encountering in my question about the DB is when I run the application from my intellij IDE, which uses my project/build/resource/main/finDB.sqlite file path. So I don't think that its a jar problem

Comment: If you run it from within IntelliJ, it will run from the `out` folder of your build, which gets refreshed on a rebuild.

Comment: Yup, you're right about that! However, I'm not recompiling my project. I'm running the project using the 'run' task provided by the gradle application plugin, closing the project, then running the application using the 'run' task again.  Between these 'run' tasks, the DB appears to refresh itself to the initial state it was in, losing all the data that had been entered for one application instance launched by the 'run' task.

Comment: If you're using Gradle, gradle itself might refresh things when it detects differences between its output folder and the project files. In addition, it is possible that gradle runs the produced jar file (I'm not sure about that).

Comment: I see...I don't think the gradle 'run' task runs the jar file though. If it did, the resource path would be directed to the resource folder within the jar itself, which doesn't appear to be the case. That gradle itself might be refreshing the build directory is a point that I've not considered, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Why not observe the actions on the actual file, then deduce what is changing?  Dump/log the `filename` variable which contains the precise path.  Check the file system meta data (creation time, modified time, etc.).  Copy the file before, during (breakpoints at appropriate spots like immediately at first line) and after running the application.  Compare the different versions of the file and determine precisely when it is changing.

Comment: From https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#command_line_interface: "the run task, which **assembles the application** and executes some script or binary."  I found no official description of the "run" task other than it is often used with plug-ins (i.e. from within IntelliJ).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610015/run-main-method-using-gradle-run-task for a hint at what it does and how the task can be configured.  The point is that as a gradle **task** it apparently does more than just execute the code.

Comment: The moral of the story is probably to store and open the database file in the user directory, or at least some other non-resource folder.  When accessing a file from a development environment, especially when that file has its origins with the source in any way (not a purely-independent external file), be aware that it may be overwritten, changed path, etc.  That is just general coding protocol.  (Similarly, unless you're executing the java file by a direct call to the java runtime, consider that *much* is happening behind the scenes by the development tools.  There is no "merely running...")

Comment: I see...thanks for the suggestion and help Perkins. I'll look into the dumping of log files, that'll probably be the most helpful way to debug what's wrong. For the time being though, I'll do what you and Mark suggest, that is to store the directory in the working directory. It's a fast method to save me a lot of grief.